# Questions on cyclic covers of the projective line

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, riemann-surfaces

Solving some exercises from Miranda's book, I stumble across cyclic covers of the projective line. In [Holomorphic maps on the cyclic cover of the projective line](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2828853/holomorphic-maps-on-the-cyclic-cover-of-the-projective-line)  I asked for a solution of one of these exercises.

Now, reading the solution and using the notations given there, I have that $Y/G$ is exactly the projective line.

I'm trying to answer to the following questions:

1) In general, given a compact Riemann surface $X$, there always exists an automorphism $\sigma$ such that $X/<\sigma>=\mathbb{P}^1$? May you provide some counterexamples or a complete proof (or some detailed reference)?

2) When it happens, are there conditions on the order of $\sigma$?

3) Assume that $X$ is a compact Riemann surface $X$ admitting an automorphism $\sigma$ such that $X/<\sigma> \simeq \mathbb{P}^1$. Does $\sigma$ fix at least a point? How many points does it fix? Is there some correlation with the genus of $X$?

4) Assume that $X$ is a cyclic cover of the projective line. Is there a birational transform such that the equation of the cover assumes the form

$$
y^n=\prod\limits_{i=1}^s (x-\alpha_i)^{m_i}
$$

with $1 \le m_i \le n-1$ (and this is easy!) and with $\sum\limits_{i=1}^s m_i \equiv 0 \pmod{n}$ (this is the part I'm interested in!)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) A "generic" compact Riemann surfaces of genus $g >2 $ do not have automorphisms. See [here.](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.kjm/1250525108)

Example: $\{ x^3y+y^3z+z^3(x-y)=0 \} \subset \mathbb{P}^2$ does not have nontrivial automorphisms.

2) Riemann-Hurwitz formula gives the restrictions. (Yes, anything can happen.)

3) You fall exactly in the situation discussed in page 73 and you have fixed points. I believe you can derive this in general from [Lefschetz fixed-point theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lefschetz_fixed-point_theorem).

4) This is equivalent to removing the ramification from $x=\infty$. Maybe it is well-known, as in [here](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs00229-006-0028-4) it is stated without proof, but I don't know a proof for this "fact".

Comment: I'm a bit confused. I know that the Klein's Riemann surface $y^7=x(x-1)^2$ has genus $3$ and its automorphism group is isomorphic to $\mathbb{P}SL(2,\mathbb{Z}/7\mathbb{Z})$. So, I don't understand why 1) holds, if a counterexample is the Klein's Riemann surface. However, I edited the question in point 1). Maybe, do you mean that for each $g>2$ there exists a Riemann surface without any non-trivial automorphism, as in the article you're posting?

Comment: The point is that a genus $g>2$ Riemann surface with an automorphism, besides the identity, is quite special.

Comment: @TheWanderer If you look for the moduli space you'll see how special these surfaces with automorphisms are.